# How to solder under already soldered parts?

Tags: soldering

I soldered several pin rows on my pcb, and thought that both sides of the pcb are already connected. Therefore I only soldered the pin rows on the bottom of the pcb. Unfortunately they weren't connected, so that I have to solder the pin rows on the upper side of the pcb, too. But with my soldering tip I am not able to get below the pin rows. Is there a way to connect them without having to unsolder them?
Pictures:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: Can you pry off the plastic part leaving the pins bare?

Comment: Added pictures, @SpehroPefhany: I try to avoid that, because the pins can be unstable afterwards...

Comment: You don't have to pry them all the way off, just half or three-quarters so you can get an iron under them.

Comment: There's no way to solder the top side with the plastic in place. You need to be able to heat both the pin and the pad at the same time, and that kind of plastic melts at soldering temperatures anyway.

Comment: I never did with that many pins, but with maybe 2x6 I could relatively easy pull of the plastic parts without damage and put it back on again.... but ymmv

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I can try that, let's see the result...

Comment: The holes are not plated through?  Maybe you can heat the pins from the backside but sneak a thin piece of solder in from the top/ side... or just gobs of solder on the back side until it flows through.  ("Oh the smell of burning plastic in the morning.")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Lever the plastic part up until it is at the top of the pins.
2. Hold each pin with angled needle-nose pliers (to prevent heat from melting the plastic) while soldering it to the top-side pad.
3. push the plastic back down.